# My visual workflow doesn't work as expected, but doesn't create an error message either

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

I have a visual flow which looks up a contact, looks up the record owner, updates the contact then creates a case.
This all seems to work, but when it creates the case, it doesn't create the case with the fields which have been selected in the flow - the fields are all blank.
Within the flow there is a decision for yes and no, going down either side allows the user to create a case on each side, but I have made sure to title all fields with yes and no, and map them appropriately.
If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the visual workflow?  At least screen shots.